# Is there a way to use WS-AtomicTransactions provided by Metro on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, java-metro-framework, wsat

The Metro documentation states that the system runs on Tomcat and Glassfish. Metro does not contain its own transaction manager. One has to deploy an external one. At system startup Metro checks whether the transaction manager is compatible. I’ve tried several ones but always Metro complains:

```
INFO: Missing required extension methods detected on 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager':
recreate
release
getTransactionRemainingTimeout
getTxLogLocation
registerRecoveryResourceHandler
```

Additional Information: I only have to call the Web Services as a client. The server is provided by someone else so redesigning the services is no option.
Does anybody know which transaction manager provides this methods and runs on Tomcat or what else I can do to use WS-AtomicTransactions on Tomcat?